# Use regex to skip a word

Tags: regex

I am using sublime to list all my .js files in my application but I want to use regex to show only the files that are not minified. I want files returned that are [NOT].min[/NOT].js I am using [^(\.min)]\.js and it appears to work but am not sure if it is going to miss any files. Is there a better piece of regex to use here?

```
/showhouse-bootstrap-datepicker.js      want returned
/dataTables.bootstrap.js                want returned
/additional-methods.min.js              dont want returned
/bootstrap-switch.min.js                dont want returned
```

I thought the following would work but it returns all .js

```
(?!\.min)\.js
```

Comment: Why d you think it would miss any files?

Comment: I am unsure of regex and am not sure if this will return all files that end in .js but not .min.js

Comment: The [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) has an answer which may be of interest: [match a string not containing a word](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406230)

Comment: I seen that post earlier but it doesnt really work for me becuase it is sperate entries. I want to find "<without_text>.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing it the `not` way , do it as a positive search.

`[^(\.min)]\.js` is what you have done. this will not match any file ending in js which have `m` or `n` or `i` in them. check it .

Use a regex like this .

```
(?<!\.min)\.js
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rJ1jN3

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text uses the Boost regex syntax, so you could use a pattern that grouped the items matching `*.min.js` and/or `*.js` then use a backreference to match the sub-expression:

```
^(.+w+\.js)|(.+\w+\.min\.js)\1$
```

The first pattern `^(.+\w+\.js)` groups anything matching `*.js` into sub-expression `1`, the second pattern `(.+\w+\.min\.js)` puts any matching `*.min.js` into sub-expression `2`. The final step is to use a back-reference to sub-expression `1`which is escaped as`\1`.

**string:**

```
something.min.js
min.js
1234.js
submin.js
file.js
admin.js
script.min.js
gar.min.js
garmin.min.js
harmin.marmin.min.js
garmin.js
```

**matched:**

```
min.js
1234.js
submin.js
file.js
admin.js
garmin.js
```